# How to handle this error message on Symfony2: Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names?

Tags: symfony, error-handling, case, classname, mismatch

I developed a website using Symfony2, and I deleted it accidentally. Unfortunately, I have succeeded to restore its source folder from the hard disk of my computer thanks to a recovery software. I have also restored the database. When testing whether the website works correctly like before or not, I figured out that there is a problem: In a page that contains a Fullcalendar calendar, when clicking on anywhere in the calendar, a pop-up window must show up containing the form of adding a new event. But what I see on my computer screen when doing that is a pop-up window containing this error message:

**Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: Ikproj\HomeBundle\Form\eventstype vs Ikproj\HomeBundle\Form\eventsType**

Then, I checked out the name of the file that is related to the form of adding a new event. And I figured out that it is **eventsType.php** (not "eventstype.php"). This is the code that such a file contains:

```
    <?php

namespace Ikproj\HomeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class eventsType extends AbstractType
{
     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title','text')
                ->add('start','datetime',array(
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i',
                    'minutes' => array(0,30)))
                ->add('end','datetime',array(
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i',
                    'minutes' => array(0,30)))
                ->add('location','text')
                ->add('description','textarea', array('attr' => array('rows' => '5','cols' => '40')));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ikproj\HomeBundle\Entity\events'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ikproj_homebundle_events';
    }
}
```

As you can notice from the code above, the name of the class is **eventsType** (not "eventstype").
Actually, everything in my website had been working very well before it was deleted accidentally. So, my questions are:

1. Why do I get that error message?
2. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by changing the call of your form in your Controller because you are probably using this:

```
use Ikproj\HomeBundle\Form\eventstype;
```

Instead of this:

```
use Ikproj\HomeBundle\Form\eventsType;
```